# git sparse-checkout to add/commit/push oneshot

Tags: git

Starting with no clone, I'm looking for the fastest way to clone (origin is on same local fs), add a few new files, push and delete clone. Can git sparse-checkout help? It could be that the files I have to add are in new directories.

Comment: If the origin is on the same FS, then what prevents you from adding the files directly on origin?

Comment: origin is bare repo

Comment: Thanks - that's a useful detail.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to optimize for speed, and if you'll be deleting the clone after the work is done (and *not doing anything with history*), then I think you'll do much better with a shallow clone:

`git clone --depth=1 --single-branch -b main /path/to/bare/repo`

This will only fetch the most recent commit (`--depth=1`) on the `main` branch (`-b main`), and no other branches or commits. Clone, make your changes, add, commit, push, and then delete.